# What does ~(tilde) means before scanf function in c++?

Tags: c++, scanf, tilde

I found a code that takes input string and print them out.

But I don't know what does the tilde means in front of the scanf.

I found tilde can be used for either destructor or binary negation but it doesn't look like both. And the code doesn't work without tilde.

```
int main() {
    char arr;

    while (~scanf("%c", &arr)){
        putchar(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf`?? Are you sure you want to use that? it is a c language fundamental. You can use `std::cin>>` instead.

Comment: Whoever wrote that is either being too clever for their own good or trying to write obfuscated code. Either way, best to throw it away. There are far better ways to read a character at a time.

Comment: This is the bitwise NOT operator. More formally, it returns the one's complement of the return value of `scanf`.

`scanf` returns the number of values it scanned successfully or `EOF` if it reaches the end of file.

`EOF` is a macro that represents a negative value. On most platforms, the value of `EOF` is `(int) -1`. In this case, taking 1's complement of `-1`, will make the value as `0` and is used to break from the loop. (Wanted to post this as an answer but was marked duplicate too soon for me to type)

Comment: `scanf("%c", &arr) == 1` would have been much easier to read. Considering that I/O is the actual bottleneck of this code, the "optimization" is somehow fruitless (even if it works (what I'm in doubt a bit as a failed `scanf()` might return 0 or EOF and I'm not sure when it does the former or the latter)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found tilde can be used for either destructor or binary negation but it doesn't look like both.

It's the [bitwise NOT operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) applied to the return value of `scanf()` as you mentioned latter.

> And the code doesn't work without tilde.

As [@Mukul Gupta explained in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55879796/what-does-tilde-means-before-scanf-function-in-c/55879809#comment98418415_55879796):

> > `scanf` returns the number of values it scanned successfully or `EOF`
> >     if it reaches the end of file. `EOF` is a macro that represents a
> >     negative value. On most platforms, the value of `EOF` is `(int) -1`.
> >     In this case, taking 1's complement of -1, will make the value as 0
> >     and is used to break from the loop.